# How to turn a user given String into Pig Latin?

Tags: java, string, loops

Im trying to turn a string taken from the user into Pig Latin. I cannot use any special classes, methods, or arrays. I can only use a Scanner to create a object to take the string from the user and .length and .charAt, in addition to any type of looping. (Also cannot use switch statements or the break keyword)

Here is an example of what my output is suppose to be:

```
Enter a line of text: this is a test.

Input : this is a line of text.
Output: his-tay is-way a-way ine-lay of-way ext-tay.
```

Here is my code, I can only get my code to work with one word and it must have a space at the end. Only one loop works at a time depending on the loop. Im not sure what to do if I get an entire String.

I know that when the user enters a space that signals a new word, and when they enter a period, that signals the ending.

Comment: Seems like a good homework question to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a hard time understanding your code.  (It looks like you are trying to do it two ways at once?)  Regardless, I believe I was able to understand your question.  Here is a compilable and runnable example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PigLatin
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.print("Enter a line of text: ");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      String text = keyboard.nextLine();

      System.out.println("\nInput: " + text);
      System.out.print("Output: ");

      if (text != null && text.length() > 0)
      {
         int i = 0;
         // this iterates through the whole string, stopping at a period or
         // the end of the string, whichever is closer
         while (i < text.length() && text.charAt(i) != '.')
         {
            // these three variables only exist in this code block,
            // so they will be re-initialized to these values
            // each time this while loop is executed
            char first = '\0'; // don't worry about this, I just use this value as a default initializer
            boolean isFirst = true;
            boolean firstIsVowel = false;
            // each iteration of this while loop should be a word, since it 
            // stops iterating when a space is encountered
            while (i < text.length()
                   && text.charAt(i) != ' '
                   && text.charAt(i) != '.')
            {
               // this is the first letter in this word
               if (isFirst)
               {
                  first = text.charAt(i);
                  // deal with words starting in vowels
                  if (first == 'a' || first == 'A' || first == 'e' || first == 'E'
                      || first == 'i' || first == 'I' || first == 'o' || first == 'O'
                      || first == 'u' || first == 'U')
                  {
                     System.out.print(first);
                     firstIsVowel = true;
                  }
                  // make sure we don't read another character as the first 
                  // character in this word
                  isFirst = false;
               }
               else
               {
                  System.out.print(text.charAt(i));
               }

               i++;
            }

            if (firstIsVowel)
            {
               System.out.print("-tay ");
            }
            else if (first != '\0')
            {
               System.out.print("-" + first + "ay ");
            }

            i++;
         }

         System.out.print('\n'); //for clean otuput
      }
   }
}
```

There are a few comments in there that might help guide you through my logic.  This is almost definitely not the most efficient way to do this (even with your limitations), as I only whipped it up as a example of the type of logic you could use.

Comment: I tried this and it works! It really makes a lot of sense. However I have a question when the program compiles, why does it run but also have an error at the end? I get a `Exception in thread main` error, but it still outputs the answer

Comment: Ah, yes, that is my mistake.  It is fixed now.  I may or may not have used the incredibly thorough test procedure of only testing with the string `This is a test.` ... It looks like strings without periods at the end failed.  Anyway, the exception was caused because the `i < text.length()` was originally after the `test.charAt(i) != ' '` in the inner while loop.  In the order they are now it will work because the while statement will fail as soon as `i < text.length()` fails, which means the `text.charAt(i)` (which is the method call that was causing the exception) is never called.

Comment: Ahh yes that makes sense, luckily it is safe to assume the user puts a period at the end, but doing that is much more thorough, thank you so much. Im going to try this again on my own now

Answer (score 0):

You could break it up into words, then process the current word when you hit a space or period:

```
System.out.print("Enter a line of text: ");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("\nInput: " + text);
System.out.print("Output: ");

String curWord = "";

for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    if (text.charAt(i) == ' ' || text.charAt(i) == '.') {
        if (curWord.charAt(0) == 'a' || curWord.charAt(0) == 'e' ||
            curWord.charAt(0) == 'i' || curWord.charAt(0) == 'o' ||
            curWord.charAt(0) == 'u') {
            System.out.print(curWord + "-way ");
        } else {
            for (int j = 1; j < curWord.length(); j++) {
                System.out.print(curWord.charAt(j);
            }
            System.out.print("-" + curWord.charAt(0) + "ay ");
            //System.out.print(curWord.substring(1)+"-"+curWord.charAt(0)+"ay ");
        }
        curWord = "";
    } else {
        curWord += text.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use .substring but that was my first thought, thanks

Comment: You don't have to use substring there then. See the updated answer.